# country state city dropdown list in nodejs and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have "country" table in "country_name": "India", "country_name": "USA" and more entry...
And second table "state" {"country_name": "India", "state": "Haryana"}, {"country_name": "USA", "state": "Texas"} and many more entry...
And the third table "city" {"state": "Haryana", "city": "Panchkula"}, {"state": "Texas", "city": "abc"} and many more entry...

And these all table in MongoDB. Now I want to show the 3 dropdown list which country select then show all respective state and then select any state then should show respective city.

I am using NodeJs but not find out an accurate solution. I am sharing here our app.js code

Please help me...Thank in advance

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var routes = require('routes');
var http = require('http');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var aa = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false});

var app = express();

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8000);
// Configure view engine to render EJS templates.
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
// app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/firstdb";

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    mongoose.connect(url, function(err, db){
        db.collection('country').find({}).toArray(function(err, result){
            if(err) throw err;
            res.render('index.html', {data: result});
            db.close();
        });
    });
});

app.post('/send', aa, function(req, res){
    var c = req.body.selectedCountry;
    mongoose.connect(url, function(err, db){
        if (err) throw err;
        var myquery = {country_name: c};
        db.collection('state').find(myquery).toArray(function(err, result){
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", result);
            res.render('index.html', {statevalue: result});
            db.close();
        });
    });
    res.end('done');
});

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log("Express server listing on port "+app.get('port'));
})
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("select.country").change(function(){
                var selectedCountry = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
                // alert(selectedCountry);
                $.post('http://localhost:8000/send', {selectedCountry:selectedCountry}, function(data){
                    if(data === 'done'){
                        // window.location.href='/';
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <select class="country">
        <option value="">Select Country</option>
        <% if(data.length) { 
        for(var i = 0; i<data.length; i++) { %>

            <option value="<%=data[i].country_name%>"><%=data[i].country_name%></option>
        <%
            }
            } else { %>
            <option value="">not found</option>
            <% } %>
    </select>
    <% if(statevalue.length)
    { %>
        <h1>hi</h1>
    <% }
     %>

</body>
</html>
```

Tables Structure:
Country Table:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d159c63de4fda6382477bf6"), "country_name" : "India" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d159c63de4fda6382477bf7"), "country_name" : "USA" }
```

state table:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d159d09de4fda6382477bf8"), "country_name" : "India", "state" : "Punjab" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d159d09de4fda6382477bf9"), "country_name" : "India", "state" : "Haryana" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d159d09de4fda6382477bfa"), "country_name" : "USA", "state" : "Texas" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d159d09de4fda6382477bfb"), "country_name" : "USA", "state" : "New York" }
```

city table:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d15b3aede4fda6382477bfc"), "state" : "Punjab", "city" : "Mohali" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d15b3aede4fda6382477bfd"), "state" : "Punjab", "city" : "Ludhiana" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d15b3aede4fda6382477bfe"), "state" : "Haryana", "city" : "Panchkula" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d15b3aede4fda6382477bff"), "state" : "Haryana", "city" : "Ambala" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d15b3aede4fda6382477c00"), "state" : "Texas", "city" : "Dallas" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d15b3aede4fda6382477c01"), "state" : "Texas", "city" : "Austin" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d15b3aede4fda6382477c02"), "state" : "New York", "city" : "Auburn" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d15b3aede4fda6382477c03"), "state" : "New York", "city" : "Fulton" }
```

Comment: Please show the document structure

Comment: document structure:
node_module,
  views/index.html, 
 app.js,
  package.json

Comment: The structure of your mongo document i.e the tables

Comment: Normally in mongodb we dont call them tables. Here are the mappings
`SQL|MongoDB
Table|Collection
Row|Document`

Comment: i have added table structure above.